# What should i do if my model has no cointegration between its variables at I (1) after using VAR for lag length selection?

Tags: vector-autoregression, cointegration, granger-causality

My main objective is to test for Granger causality, my variables become stationary after first when test of ADF annd PP was applied.From my correlation analysis i detected a strong correlation between two variables, but they failed to cointegrate. How do i know that my variables are integrated ? [image]
Please what should i do to have meaningful results.

Comment: I do not quite understand your question. Have you tested for whether your variables are integrated with an ADF test? If so, have you found them to be integrated? If so, have you tested for cointegration with a Johansen test og Engle-Granger test? If so, what result are you getting?

Comment: Yes i tested for integration with ADF and they were stationary after first difference, and i tested for cointegration by johansen method but the results showed no cointegration between my variables. Please I don`t know what to do next in order to have meaningful causality results.

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions from Dave Giles' blog that I linked in a comment to your previous post?

Comment: Yes I tried but i still don`t have meaningful results, i had p=1 after developing a VAR of the variables at levels. And still had no results for cointegration, and also the null hypothesis for non-granger causality was accepted at 5% for all the variables.

Comment: Well, if the variables are not cointegrated, then neither a VAR in levels nor a VECM will make sense. You should use a VAR in first differences.

Comment: OK professor thank you so much for your suggestion.

Comment: Please Prof, i just used a VAR at first differences, and i conducted an autocorrelation test on its residuals which proved not to have any autocorrelation. But still i had no  meaningful results for causality between the variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "no meaningful results"? If you were able to conduct the test, you must have gotten an answer which is either to reject the H0 or fail to reject. Both are meaningful results. One says there is Granger causality, the other fails to find evidence for that.

Comment: Good day prof my H0 fail to reject indicating there was no causality relationship between the variables (Neutrality hypothesis), Please Sir, my point is that which other empirical analysis could i run to confirm the results i have for this time series data. And please what interpretation could i make for the variables not been cointegrated.

Comment: Added to this Sir, previous panel empirical study done on the same variable but at different periods (1971-2001) tend to suggest a unidirectional causality between two of the variables, how could i relate this to my own results which suggest no causality.

Comment: You may post this as a seperate question. In it, tell us what analysis you have run and what results you got (just like you told this in the comments) and ask for help starting from there.

Comment: If your objective is to test for Granger Causality, then I am confused why you're looking at correlation and cointegration. These are 3 different concepts. Zero in on Granger Causality.